# AWS ELB : How to know which ELB is forwarding Requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

We have certain instances which are used by multiple load balancers/target groups. Is there a way to know which request is getting forwarded by which ELB. I don't control most of the code, can it be done without changing any code.
I am aware about X-Forwarded-For/Proto/Port and don't think these can be used.

Comment: Check the `Host` header.

Comment: @MarkB you mean HTTP_HOST that contains the domain in browser like   www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

Great question. Enabling logging for your ELBs might be able to help you find what you are looking for:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/access-log-collection.html

The logs are organized by the name of the Load Balancer and placed into S3 buckets of your choosing. The link above enumerates the metadata logged. Logging does not incur additional charges, but you are charged for the storage cost of S3. This would be done through the AWS Console, and would not require you to change any application code (but you might need to do some scripting to analyze the generated log files).

Comment: I can see a pattern in logs, but the IPs keep on changing. We want to host two websites for different geographies with same runtime environment. I understand I can use Route 53 to divert traffic on different load balancers, but I am not finding a way to differentiate. I can't use CF here because of dynamic content. I am already serving static through it.

Comment: If what you want to do is direct traffic from a specific geography to a specific ELB, maybe the best way to do this is through a Route 53 Geolocation Routing Policy?http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo

Comment: One more comment, you can never get the Public IP of a ELB, AWS only will provide you with the DNS name. I think this is because the IPs are subject to change, maybe this would explain the changing IPs you are seeing as they are never static with regards to ELBs

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can dig the IP of your load balancers and search for them in the logs. You will need to poll the ELB IP as it will change within few minutes. That's how it works. 
This will only work if real IP is not enabled.

Comment: Is there a way to Poll for private Ip's associated with load balancer?